# How do I insert the values of range items to a sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

This macro compares two columns of two different worksheets and shows the values which are new and have been deleted.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to insert the items in d1 and d3 into the active worksheet (it's not working as shown below). The piece is highlighted in the code.

Can anyone help?

```
Sub test()
    Dim e As Range
    Dim shA As Worksheet
    Dim shB As Worksheet

    'Objekte festlegen
    Set d1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set d2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set d3 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set shA = Worksheets(Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy"))
    Set shB = Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Index - 1)

    'Füge ICM Nummern des alten Tabellenblattes Objekten zu
    With shB
        For Each e In .Cells(2, 1).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row)
            d1(e) = True
            d2(e) = True
        Next e
    End With

    'Neue und alte ICM Nummern bestimmen
    With shA
        For Each e In .Cells(2, 1).Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row)
            If (d2(e)) * (d1.exists(e)) Then d1.Remove e
            If Not d2(e) Then d3(e) = True
    Next e

    'Objekte transponieren und einfügen in aktuelles Tabellenblatte unter ICM Abzug
```

> ```
>     On Error Resume Next
>         .Cells(2, 10).Resize(d1.Count) = .Application.Transpose(d1.keys)
>         .Cells(2, 11).Resize(d3.Count) = .Application.Transpose(d3.keys)
>     On Error GoTo 0
>     End With
> ```

```
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but you will need toloop through the `keys` and add the values 1 by 1

Comment: Continuing from @ShaiRado comments: or you can use array.. which you can then transpose

Answer (score 0):

Looping is not allways that bad, it will take no time to get the `Key`s of the 2 `Dictionary` objects.

```
Dim Key As Variant

With shA
    i = 2
    For Each Key In d1.keys
        .Cells(i, 10).Value = Key       
        i = i + 1
    Next Key

    i = 2
    For Each Key In d3.keys
        .Cells(i, 1).Value = Key        
        i = i + 1
    Next Key
End With
```